# C# MSMQ MessageQueue Id - How to get Valid Guid

Tags: c#, .net, message-queue, msmq, sendmessage

I tried to send a message in a Local Queue as well as in the Remote Queue.

The Sample Source is

```
Guid queueId;

try
{
    MessageQueue rmQ = new MessageQueue("FormatName:Direct=TCP:192.168.5.26\\Private$\\RemoteQueue");
    //MessageQueue rmQ = new MessageQueue(".\\Private$\\LocalQueue");
    rmQ.Send("Once again Mr.John Please come here...");

    queueId = rmQ.Id;
}
catch (ArgumentException ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
catch (MessageQueueException ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
```

In all the Scenario I am getting `Guid.Empy` but the message is queuing successfully in the respective machine's Message Queue.

Kindly review the following snapshot

[image]

Kindly assist me how to get the Valid **`MessageQueue.Id`**

Comment: Are you sure you want the queue ID? Or do you want the message ID?

Comment: But did you read MSDN on the `ID`?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.messaging.messagequeue.id(v=vs.110).aspx says "Message Queuing sets the Id property when it creates the queue. This property is only available for public queues."

Comment: I think you didn't read the last part of @rbm's comment/the msdn docs. You're accessing a _private_ queue and that doesn't seem to _have_ an Id.

Comment: Correct, i've added it as an aswer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access an ID of a private queue, which is unsupported. MSDN says:

> Message Queuing sets the Id property when it creates the queue. This
>   property is only available for public queues.

See

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.messaging.messagequeue.id(v=vs.110).aspx